# How to change number of pages to be displayed on datatable pagination

Tags: datatable, pagination

I want to control the `number of pages` being displayed in pagination of Data table. I have searched a lot and I always get `page.length` option of Data table. Actually my problem is, the pages on desktop view seems to be fine as:
[![Desktop pagination][1]][1]

But as soon as I get into `mobile view`, the pagination breaks and looks like:

[![Mobile pagination][2]][2]

So I want the pagination to be in a `single row` and therefore, I want to reduce the number of pages displaying in pagination. So in mobile view, it should be like `previous 1 2 ... 19 next` but in desktop view, it remain the same.

The code I have used to initialize datatable is:

```
$('.products-server-side-data-table').DataTable({// eslint-disable-line new-cap
    'autoWidth': false,
    'processing': true,
    'serverSide': true,
    'pageLength': 10,
    'sort': false,
    'info' : true,
    'searching': true,
    'ajax': {
             //ajax call
}
```

I have tried different options like:

```
"pagingType": "full_numbers_no_ellipses"
```

```
"sPaginationType": "four_button"
```

and

```
"sPaginationType": "listbox"
```

But none of them changed pagination even a bit. Please help me.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlWGG.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ALel.png

Comment: I am not sure why images are not displaying... but anyways link at the bottom have images....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer for this. In order to set the `number of pagination button`, the following jquery function is helpful:

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.pager.numbers_length = 5;
```

Reference:
[change number of pagination button Datatable](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/34131/can-i-change-number-of-pagination-buttons#Comment_91309)